# jquery image map area dynamic onclick

Tags: jquery

I cant get me head around this one...

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div>
        <a>OOOO</a>
    </div>

    <img src="./plusminus.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="PlusMinus" usemap="#plusminus" />
    <map name="plusminus">
      <area class="plus" shape="poly" coords="8,0,12,0,20,11,15,11,15,18,5,18,5,12,0,12,0,9" alt="Plus" href="#" />
      <area class="minus" shape="poly" coords="15,11,26,11,26,16,29,16,29,19,21,29,17,29,11,20,11,18,15,18" alt="Minus" href="#" />
    </map>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div>
        <a>OOOO</a>
    </div>

    <img src="./plusminus.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="PlusMinus" usemap="#plusminus" />
    <map name="plusminus">
      <area class="plus" shape="poly" coords="8,0,12,0,20,11,15,11,15,18,5,18,5,12,0,12,0,9" alt="Plus" href="#" />
      <area class="minus" shape="poly" coords="15,11,26,11,26,16,29,16,29,19,21,29,17,29,11,20,11,18,15,18" alt="Minus" href="#" />
    </map>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() { //run when the DOM is ready
    $('a').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('hilight');
    });

    $('.plus').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('hilight');
    });
});
```

The `a` tags perform as required but when the image map is clicked it only highlights the top div not the one clicked??

Comment: JAVA != JavaScript, FYI.

Comment: You could also use `$('a').closest('.wrap');`

Comment: @tymeJV I feel like this should be on the home page of SO

Comment: @mishik Yes... It would be great to have a kind of "Flash breaking new" module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have 2 maps, but both have the same name.  The browser is applying each map to the first image with a matching map attribute.  I changed the HTML to use two unique names for your maps.  Here's a working version of your code.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div>
        <a>OOOO</a>
    </div>

    <img src="./plusminus.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="PlusMinus" usemap="#plusminus1" />
    <map name="plusminus1">
      <area class="plus" shape="poly" coords="8,0,12,0,20,11,15,11,15,18,5,18,5,12,0,12,0,9" alt="Plus" href="#" />
      <area class="minus" shape="poly" coords="15,11,26,11,26,16,29,16,29,19,21,29,17,29,11,20,11,18,15,18" alt="Minus" href="#" />
    </map>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div>
        <a>OOOO</a>
    </div>

    <img src="./plusminus.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="PlusMinus" usemap="#plusminus2" />
    <map name="plusminus2">
      <area class="plus" shape="poly" coords="8,0,12,0,20,11,15,11,15,18,5,18,5,12,0,12,0,9" alt="Plus" href="#" />
      <area class="minus" shape="poly" coords="15,11,26,11,26,16,29,16,29,19,21,29,17,29,11,20,11,18,15,18" alt="Minus" href="#" />
    </map>
</div>
```

JavaScript: (note- not Java)

```
$(function() { //run when the DOM is ready
    $('a, .plus').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.wrap').toggleClass('hilight');
    });
});
```

Please also note that I condensed your script.  You were applying the same actions to both selectors, so I simplified it to use both selectors.  If you prefer it, your original JavaScript will still work.  Here's a jsfiddle link showing this code working:  http://jsfiddle.net/GzxQR/

Credit to @Brewal for suggesting `$('a').closest('.wrap');` - this is simpler code and is less likely to break if you change your HTML.

Comment: Sweet, Thanks... these divs are generated dynamically, will add a counter. thanks again.

Comment: There you go, a counter is a nice easy fix.

Comment: `$('.wrap').on('click', 'a, .plus', function() { $(this).toggleClass('hilight'); });` is even nicer.